# IE Automation (IE8) using VBA and Input type "hidden"

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am using vba to automate a site in Internet Explorer. I have been very successful to this point. The issue I am running into is that there is an input field and the type is "hidden" and not text. How do I get around this? I know there is got to be a way.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I guess you are processing the web form, so could you please share the HTML content of the form? And any your VBA code?

Comment: Better if you show the code you tried and explain exactly what errors you got, or what's not working.  Typically one you have reference set to a hidden form field you can set its Value just as you would for a regular text input field.

Answer (score 2):

The below example demonstrates how to refer to input elements by index in loop:

```
Sub Test()
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True
    ' navigate and download the web page
    objIE.Navigate "https://www.yahoo.com/"
    Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4 Or objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ' retrieve document object
    Set objDocument = objIE.document
    ' retrieve forms collection
    Set colForms = objDocument.forms
    ' retrieve the first form object by index
    Set objForm = colForms(0)
    ' retrieve the form input tags collection
    Set colInputTags = objForm.getElementsByTagName("input")
    ' loop through all input tags in the form
    For n = 0 To colInputTags.Length - 1
        ' refer to the certain input tag by index
        Set objInputTag = colInputTags(n)
        ' output
        Debug.Print n _
            & " (" & objInputTag.Type & ") " _
            & objInputTag.Name & " = " _
            & objInputTag.Value
    Next
    ' refer to input tag #0
    Set objElement = colInputTags(0)
    ' hide the search inputbox
    objElement.Type = "hidden"
    ' refer to input tag #4
    Set objElement = colInputTags(4)
    ' output the current value
    Debug.Print "#4 value = " & objElement.Value
    ' cnange the value
    objElement.Value = "input tag #4"
    ' cnange the type
    objElement.Type = "Text"
    ' refer to input tag #5
    Set objElement = colInputTags(5)
    ' cnange the value
    objElement.Value = "input tag #5"
    ' cnange the type
    objElement.Type = "Text"
    ' quit IE
    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

The code gives for me the following output:

[image: immediate window]

As you can see, it hides the main input tag, outputs the value of the hidden input tag #4, and change the type and the values of #4 and #5, so the web page looks like:

[image: modified web page]

Comment: Than you very much for your help. I am still confused on how to get text elements into a input box that's type "hidden" I cant seem to get that value to change.

Comment: @hockeybo97, I added description how to change hidden input content.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have gotten the value to change successfully. My challenge now is how to get it into the input box on the form. Here is an example of the source code.<input name = "AssignedTextBox" type="hidden"
id="InputIDName" value> I want to get the Input Name to equal the value I specify.

Comment: No matter how I seem to code. I cannot get the input box to populate a value. Is there a way to change the source with vba to type = "Text"?

Comment: @hockeybo97, I added an example on how to change type and value of input elements. If you need further elaborations, please update your answer: add the code you run, the result and description what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

You can use a CSS selector to target those elements of `input[type='hidden']`. This reads as elements with `input` tag, having attribute `type`, with value `'hidden'`.

---

**CSS query (sample results):**

[image: CSS query]

---

**Sheet before (sample):**

[image: Before]

---

**Sheet after (sample):**

[image: After]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the css selectors with the `querySelectorAll` method of `document` and then loop the length of the returned nodeList.

I make visible by swopping the `"hidden"` value with `vbNullString` and assign a value using the `value` attribute.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AlterHidden()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, aNodeList As Object, i As Long
    Const URL As String = "https://uk.yahoo.com"
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        On Error GoTo noCookieRequest
        .document.querySelector("input[value='OK']").Click '<==On time required for cookies
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
noCookieRequest:
       Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set aNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("input[type='hidden']")
        On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While aNodeList Is Nothing
        For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
            With aNodeList.item(i)
                .Type = vbNullString
                .Value = "Surprise " & i
            End With
        Next i
        Stop                                     '<== Delete me
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```